# Spring Security injecting null @AuthenticatedPrincipal into controllers

Tags: java, spring-security

Java 11, Spring Security here. I have the following endpoint/method in my `@RestController`:

```
@GetMapping("/centerPoint")
public void centerPoint(@AuthenticationPrincipal ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken token,
          HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            
  Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  if (auth == null) {
    LOGGER.warn("Current authentication instance from security context is null");
    response.sendRedirect("some redirect url");
    return;
  }

  SAMLCredential attributes = ((SAMLCredential) token.getCredentials());
  // ...rest of code omitted for brevity
  
}
```

When I set a breakpoint inside this method and login to my app, `token` is `null` (meaning it was not properly injected as an `@AuthenticatedPrincipal`) **however** `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns an `Authentication` instance that looks totally fine. I get a NPE when the `token.getCredentials()` gets called at the bottom there.

I know this is an incomplete code snippet and I'm happy to provide other parts of the security code (`WebSecurityConfig`, etc.) however I'm wonder: what would cause `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` to be non-null, but not have a `token` to inject?

Comment: (the) anonymous user!? (e.g. when the endpoint is: `authenticated()...permitAll()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc in `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver` says the following:

> Will resolve the CustomUser argument using Authentication.getPrincipal() from the
> SecurityContextHolder. If the Authentication or
> Authentication.getPrincipal() is null, it will return null. If the
> types do not match, null will be returned unless
> AuthenticationPrincipal.errorOnInvalidType() is true in which case a
> ClassCastException will be thrown.

So you should make sure that the `Authentication.getPrincipal()` type is `ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken`.

Debug your application and see which type returns from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` and from `authentication.getPrincipal()`